# Problem with loading html into paragraph TextFrame.Paragraphs.AddFromHtml() with Aspose.Slides

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose-slides

I have problem with importing html text into paragraphs. I know Aspose.Slides support BASIC text import along with LIMITED tag support but can anyone from the Aspose support team share which tags and styles are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed your requirements and like to share that while importing HTML, Aspose.Slides consider basic tags like font families, color, height, italicizing, text boldness, Paragraphs and bullets.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.